# How to display a class within a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to display the "tab2" using Javascript? If I use 
`document.getElementByClassName("modal")[0].style.display = 'block';`

tab1 will display. if I change the [0] nothing appears.

```
<div class = "modal"> 
     <div class = "tab1">
         ...
     </div>
     <div class = "tab2">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I forgot to tell that modal is display: none is the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple elements with the same class name, hence you have to use the plural "get elements", and the method returns an list of matching elements. You can reach the tabs using the `children` property :

```js
function showNthModal (n) {
  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
  var modal = modals[n - 1];
  modal.style.display = "block";
  showNthTab(modal, 2);
}
function showNthTab (parent, n) {
  var tab = parent.children[n];
  tab.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
div{display:none;border:1px solid black;padding:0 1em;}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="showNthModal(1)">Show modal1</button>
  <button onclick="showNthModal(2)">Show modal2</button>
</p>
<div class="modal">
  <p>modal1</p>
  <div class="tab1"><p>tab1</p></div>
  <div class="tab2"><p>tab2</p></div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <p>modal2</p>
  <div class="tab1"><p>tab1</p></div>
  <div class="tab2"><p>tab2</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector(".tab2").style.display = 'block';
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".modal .tab2").style.display = 'block';
```

In your HTML you only have ONE element with class modal, hence there is only one element in the

```
document.getElementsByClassName("modal")
```

collection and that is the outer div. Collections are zero based, hence the [0]

If you want to access tab2, use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab2")[0]
```

or better:

```
document.querySelector(".tab2")
```

as already mentioned

NOTE: There is nothing called `document.getElementByClassName` in singular. I assume a typo

UPDATE: I strongly suggest you set an ID on each div and give the tabs a class. You will need to hide them all and then show one and then show the parent

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector("#tab2").style.display="block"; // unhide tab2
  document.querySelector("#modal1").style.display="block"; // show parent
}
```

```css
#modal1 { display: none}
.tab { display: none}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal1"> 
     <div class = "tab" id="tab1">
         Tab 1
     </div>
     <div class = "tab" id="tab2">
         Tab 2
     </div>
</div>
```

More complex:

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var buts = document.querySelectorAll(".tabBut");
  for (var i=0;i<buts.length;i++) { 
    buts[i].onclick=function() {
      var showTab = this.getAttribute("data-tab"), tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
      for (var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
        tabs[i].style.display=tabs[i].id==showTab?"block":"none";
      }  
      document.querySelector("#modal1").style.display="block"; // show parent
    }
  }  
}
```

```css
#modal1 { display: none}
.tab { display: none}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="tabBut" data-tab="tab1">Tab 1</button>
<button type="button" class="tabBut" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal1"> 
     <div class="tab" id="tab1">
         Tab 1
     </div>
     <div class="tab" id="tab2">
         Tab 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that modal is `display: none` in the beginning

Comment: @GamingRuru I fail to see from your question why the code I wrote is not answering your question in full.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0].lastChild.style.display = "block";
```

Note that it's `getElementsByClassName`. You need the `[0]` to get the first matching element.

Then you can use `lastChild` to reference tab2. Or you could use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab2")[0].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Or `document.querySelector(".tab2").style.display = "block"`

Comment: I forgot to tell that modal is `display: none` in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

To access the div *"tabs"* classes from the div with class *"modal"*, you should use the `childNodes` property in this way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0].childNodes[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Now, you only have to change the index in the collection returned by `childNodes` to reach each tab separately. You can even use the `length` property to know how many tabs are inside the parent div like this `numTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0].childNodes.length` and with that information do a for loop and modify each one as you seem fit.

I would recomend to use an id for the parent div, and use the method `getElementById()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`, so in case you use the "modal" class again in another element, you don't get a undesired behaviour on your code while using `getElementsByClassName("modal")[0]` as the index of your targeted div may change.

One last remark, as @mplungjan already mentioned, in your question `document.getElementByClassName` is missing an "s". It should be `document.getElementsByClassName`